# Renpy pasteable input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, renpy

A game I'm working on needs an input in which a special code can be pasted. The code is a random hash of 24 characters, which would be hard for players to write manually. I haven't found any good quality ways of implementing such an input.

Could this be even done? And if so, how?

I'm just started with Renpy not so long ago and my knowledge is currently scarce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://renpy.org/doc/html/screens.html?highlight=input).

> #### Input
>
> Creates a text input area, which allows the user to enter text. When > the user presses return, the text will be returned by the interaction.
>
> **copypaste**
>
> If True, it becomes possible to copy and paste into this input. (By
> default, disabled.)

Just set `copypaste=True`

Comment: Oh I haven't given that a reasonable read, thank you so much!